# Showing message before page refresh using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display ajax result message before page refresh, but something is wrong. My code is like this:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "@(Url.RouteUrl("DummyRequest"))",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.Success) {
            $('#dummy-notification').text(data.Result).fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
            setInterval(function () {
                location.reload();
            }, 5000);
        }
        else {
            $('#dummy-notification').text(data.Result).fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
            /*setInterval(function () {
                location.reload();
            }, 5000);*/
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $('#dummy-notification').text("Something went wrong.").fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
    }
});
```

My code is working just fine on **else** situation. When I tried, message appears, then after 5 secs page reloads itself. But when **if** situation is on, page reloads itself, however message doesn't show.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: console errors?

Comment: use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

Comment: Have you tried a callback and setTimeout?

Comment: @sagarpatro I've tried it either, didn't work.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob Can you give me an example code?

Comment: Can you console.log or alert data.Result - is it even defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its depends on response time of server.. so if response from server is late then not working correctly.. so you have to wait for AJAX response then you have to display popup and redirect. so use ajax option `async: false` in your ajax request. as mentioned below

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "@(Url.RouteUrl("DummyRequest"))",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.Success) {
            $('#dummy-notification').text(data.Result).fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
            setInterval(function () {
                location.reload();
            }, 5000);
        }
        else {
            $('#dummy-notification').text(data.Result).fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
            /*setInterval(function () {
                location.reload();
            }, 5000);*/
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $('#dummy-notification').text("Something went wrong.").fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: **async: false** fixed the problem. Thank you very much @HareshVidja.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('#dummy-notification').text(data.Result).fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        location.reload();
    }, 5000);
});
```

The difference is that the `setTimeout()` will not be called until after the `fadeOut()` is finished executing.

Comment: Didn't work either. It reloads the page after 8 secs, but no msg.